# Symlinks to executables in `/Applications` cannot run

Tags: terminal, symlink

I'm trying to create a symlink to emacs, in order to let git use it as default editor.

```
ln -s /Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs emacs
```

Calling `/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs` directly from terminal works.

Calling `./emacs` in that folder gives a pop-up that says:

> "This application will not run on your computer. Sorry!"

The symlink has permissions `rwxr-xr-x`.

I don't feel this is related to emacs, I've tried other applications. For example chess:

```
$ /Applications/Chess.app/Contents/MacOS/Chess # working
$ ln -s /Applications/Chess.app/Contents/MacOS/Chess chess
$ ./chess
2017-04-19 14:39:05.479 chess[16972:4178764] No Info.plist file in application bundle or no NSPrincipalClass in the Info.plist file, exiting
```

How can I make a working executable symlink to an application in `/Applications`?

(next step is to go through a script instead of a symlink, but I'd rather use a symlink.)

Comment: Is there a reason not to just make the symlink to the app (.app) instead of something within its contents?

Comment: @NoahL: I'm not sure I get what you mean. It's a directory?